# Unknown field(s) () specified for Offer

Tags: python, django, model, django-generic-views

I'm quite new to django and currently have a problem, which I trouble to solve

I'm getting

> Unknown field(s) () specified for Offer

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Buyer, Seller, Offer

class OfferCreate(CreateView):
    model = Offer
    fields = ['category', 'car_brand', 'car_model', 'type', 'year_of_production', 'color', 'car_mileage', 'description',
              'car_equipment', 'fuel_type', 'doors_number', 'seats_number', 'engine_capacity',
              'seller', 'photos', '',]
    success_url = reverse_lazy("/")
```

model Offer

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    car_brand = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    car_model = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORY)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE)
    year_of_production = models.SmallIntegerField()
    color = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    car_mileage = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    car_equipment = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=EQUIP)
    fuel_type = models.IntegerField(choices=FUEL_TYPE)
    doors_number = models.IntegerField(choices=DOORS_NUMBER)
    seats_number = models.IntegerField(choices=SEATS_NUMBER)
    engine_capacity = models.IntegerField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photos = models.ImageField(upload_to='offers')
```

Any idea what is causing a problem?

Comment: What is `, ''` in the fields (last item)?

Comment: it shouldn't be there, without it i get: "Unknown field(s) (car_equipment) specified for Offer"

Comment: well `car_equipent is indeed not a model field, you used a *form field*, so it is not stored in the database. Model fields are fields on a model, form fields specify what a user enters in a form.

Comment: ok, got it. Thank You.